# Can I use my Bluetooth headset as a microphone?

Tags: 11.04, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I have a [Motorola S305](http://j.mp/nf7Leu) Bluetooth headset which I use with my computer often for headphones. I've been using them for a while and have been really pleased with the sound quality, form factor, and battery life.

The only thing is that I haven't found a way to use them as a microphone yet. Is there a way for me to use them for a microphone so that I can seamlessly use them for Skype and other applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the *Sound Preferences* menu we select the *Input* tab to choose our Bluetooth device (here depicted for a Philips headset) for audio input:

[image]

In order to use your headset for telephony we will also have to make sure, that the hardware is set to *Duplex* mode in *Hardware -> Settings*:

[image]

**Note:** In duplex mode the sound quality may not be very high due to usage of the HSP/HFP codecs.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Unfortunately, it makes sound quality horrible if trying to play anything other than a phone call.

Comment: For "better" sound quality choose A2DP for playback (however still this may be far from CD quality). The microphone unfortunately is not available in A2DP mode.

Comment: Roger that. It's just a bummer that no mode exists to make the microphone available over A2DP.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience (yet) on that but it may be possible that by introducing L2CAP in Linux kernel 3.0 (11.10) this feature could be made available (if somebody codes drivers).

Comment: Why is the microphone not available in a2dp mode? Hardware or Software limitations? I can't get my head around it..

Comment: @Tapper: This is a limtation of the [A2DP specification](http://developer.bluetooth.org/KnowledgeCenter/TechnologyOverview/Pages/ImplementingAdvancedAudioDistributionProfile.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I have no explicit solution but the bug ticket for this:
[#508522](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/508522)

Perhaps sometimes there will be the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the sound menu and select "Audio preferences", then you'll get a dialog where one of the pages is called "Inputs" or similar. You should be able to see your headphones as an input source there.

Answer (score -4):

Just try talking into the headsets and see if it work.

Comment: Lol. You win the "Sarcastic Answer of the Year" award!