# Setting up a bluetooth audio-microphone headset on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone

I recently purchased a Henson BTH033 bluetooth headset with a built in microphone. I would ideally like to use it as my primary audio-microphone output-input on my ubuntu install.

Here is my progress so far:

I have paired and connected the headset using the stock bluetooth interface in the settings, the one that is also listed in the top-bar menu. It connects successfully every time.

However, the device is not listed as either an audio or microphone option in the sound settings, and does not receive sound when music is playing. Strangely though, the controls on the headset successfully pause, play and skip music playing on my computer.

What do you suggest that I do in order to get the bluetooth i/o recognised in sound menu and working? thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried checking the settings in pavucontrol? See also [No sound from bluetooth headset, but its detected](http://askubuntu.com/q/239209/88802) and [Accidentally changed Bluetooth mode to off](http://askubuntu.com/q/187915/88802)

Comment: Please also note that you cant use your microphone in HSP/HFP mode: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61031/can-i-use-my-bluetooth-headset-as-a-microphone

Comment: Takkat and gertvdijk thanks, I have read all those links before, but I was feeling optimistic about the microphone :) and with regards to pavucontrol there is still no mention of any audio bluetooth devices unfortunately. Maybe I'm missing a driver or something?

Comment: I found a solution to this dilemma. I just used Ubuntu Software Centre to download blueman applet 1.23, worked within minutes. Cool :)

Comment: @user2087941 Add that as an answer, rather than a comment! :)

Answer (score 4):

Download "Bluetooth manager" from software center.

Open it.

Search for devices.

Right click on the device and choose "Audio sink" option. You are all done.  :D

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this dilemma. I just used Ubuntu Software Centre to download blueman applet 1.23, worked within minutes. Cool :) Thanks or all the advice everyone